# How do I get the values in the attribute when changing the checkbox status using pure js?

Tags: javascript

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox"  id="status" data="1" class="cgroup">
    <input type="checkbox"  id="status" data="2" class="cgroup">
    <input type="checkbox"  id="status" data="3" class="cgroup">
</form>
```

**im try this code:**
But it only shows the data of the first inputbox ('1')

```
document.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var id=document.getElementById('status').getAttribute('data')
    console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: your issue is, that your `id` is not unique ... so `document.getElementById('status')` always gets the FIRST one - look at using `function(e)` and then `e` will be an event that will have a property for which input was changed

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can get the `data` if you first select all elements using querySelectorAll and then loop over it to add the `change` event on all the `checkbox`.

**2)** You should also change the `id` of each `input` since id should be unique

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".cgroup");
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data'));
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="status1" data="1" class="cgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="status2" data="2" class="cgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="status3" data="3" class="cgroup">
</form>
```

Comment: if you change the ids to be unique, your answer will be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Be be reminded that the `id` need to be unique in the DOM.

Use the `document.querySelectorAll()` to find your elements. This could be expanded with a class, parent tag and such.

```js
const getValues = () => {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
  const array = []
  for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
    array.push(checkbox.value)
  }
  console.log(array)
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="status1" value="1" class="cgroup">1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="status2" value="2" class="cgroup">2</input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="status3" value="3" class="cgroup">3</input>
</form>

<button type="button" onClick="getValues()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `getElementsByClassName` like

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var values = []; 
  var inputCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cgroup');
  for(var i=0; inputCheckboxes[i]; ++i){
        if(inputCheckboxes[i].checked){
             values.push(inputCheckboxes[i].getAttribute('data'));
        }
  }
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" data="1" class="cgroup">
    <input type="checkbox" data="2" class="cgroup">
    <input type="checkbox" data="3" class="cgroup">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "queryselectorAll" to selected each checkbox and write appropriate function to get output.For detail explanation visit- https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-checkbox/